# How do you arrange items in a table layout in SilverLight?

Tags: silverlight, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I am stumped. I've got a collection of items that I'm binding to an `ItemsControl` and would like them arranged as a grid rather than strictly vertically or horizontally. All of the examples I've used in WPF are not supported in Silverlight like using the `ItemContainerStyle` or `SharedSizeGroup` and the Silverlight toolkit WrapPanel does not appear to support data binding.

Is there something I am missing or does it need to be built from scratch in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine `ItemsControl` **with** `WrapPanel`.  Specify the `WrapPanel` in a `ItemsPanelTemplate` on the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` property.